# Not able to print logs to Tomcat's CATALINA_BASE by using log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I have update our code from log4j to log4j 2.17.1 And I want to stored the log file to servers under the Apache tomcat. I am using the log4j2.properties mentioned below.

[image]

When I run the code, then the logs file is printed in under code structure(see in below attached screenshot)but I want to print the  logs file in QA-Servers under apache tomcat.

[image]

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Please add your `log4j2.properties` as **text**, not an image. This will help people having the same problem as you have to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** use `${sys:catalina.base}`.

The property substitution in Log4j 2.x differs from Log4j 1.x (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution)). The most prominent change is that:

- in Log4j 1.x `${catalina.base}` is looked up in Java system properties and, if the system property does not exist, in the configuration file,
- in Log4j 2.x `${catalina.base}` is looked up **only** in the configuration file.

In both cases if the property can not be resolved the placeholder is left unchanged.

In Log4j 2.x all external property lookups must be prefixed using an appropriate prefix. The exact equivalent of Log4j 1.x behavior is `${sys:catalina.base}`. Therefore you can use:

```
# Fallback
property.catalina.base=.
appender.rolling.fileName=${sys:catalina.base}/logs/aseq_wiptmobile_qa-1.applog
```

Comment: by using ${sys:catalina.base} this is not working. log file is printed under the code directory. Giving an error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"